# Could someone hack into my website through http ports?

Tags: http, ports

Let's say ports 80 and 443 open for my website hosted by Amazon AWS. Could someone figure out a way to exploit somehow or is that just nearly impossible and something no one would need to worry about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have a server which executes arbitrary commands send from a connecting client without any kind of authentication. It is obvious that such a server could be easily hacked by any client which can reach the server - no matter if the client connects to port 80 with plain HTTP, port 443 with encrypted HTTPS, port 25 (mail), ...

While nobody sane would be willingly setup such a server, this is basically what an application with a critical security issue looks from the perspective of an attacker - it allows Remote Code Execution (RCE) due to bugs in the application. And there are often such critical security issues in widely used software.

The port itself does not matter for this, nor does it matter if the connection between client and server is encrypted. All what matters is that there is some application which accepts data on this port and acts on these data in an insecure way.

Answer (score 5):

You don't hack or exploit ports. You hack or exploit the services that are running behind the port. What a person can do depends entirely on what service they're able to reach behind your http port. You could have a web server there, an ftp server, or a tea pot.

What the person would be able to do depends on whats running there, if anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just like on any open port, the possibility of exploitation is fully dependent on the services you are hosting behind them. Port 80 and 443 are most used for HTTP(S) services and thus should be opened if you want your website to work on the public internet.

Generally, using an up-to-date, well-configured and well-known web server would mitigate most security risks on the transport layer.